# Creating new Instance with a Through association Sails.js/waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In my model I have a many-to-many-through association between `User`, `Program` through `ProgramStaff`:

User.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        programs: {
            collection: 'Program',
            via: 'program',
            through: 'programstaff'
        }
    }
}
```

Program.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        personnel:{
            collection : 'User',
            via: 'user',
            through: 'programstaff'
        }
    }
}
```

ProgramStaff.js:

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        program: {
            model: 'Program'
        },
        user: {
            model: 'User'
        },
        permissions: {
            type: 'integer'
        }
    },
    tableName: 'program_staff'
};
```

(I need to program-staff through table to hold some sort of permissions and a user-program based, otherwise, I'd just use a regular many-to-many association).

My question is - can I create a new `User' and associate with (existing)`Program` using the rest or shortcuts routes?

I've tried to send

```
user.programs = [programId];  // doesn't do anything (or error)
//or
user.programs = [{program: progamId}]; // creates new program even though I send valid id of existing program
//or
user.programs = [{program: { id: progamId}}]; // error
```

But neither seem to create the ProgramStaff record.

P.S. I know I can do it with a `User.create` and a nested `ProgramStaff.create` calls within a route, or a Create and then Update rest/shortcut calls but I was wondering about a "automatic" way to do that.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?